# How do i stop a thread created by _beginthreadex from hanging in win32

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi, winsock

I am trying to learn winsock and i am at the point where i am trying to make a server handle multiple requests and came across this answer: 
[TCP Winsock: accept multiple connections/clients](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15185380/tcp-winsock-accept-multiple-connections-clients)

All well and good, now i have a code that looks like this(I will skip the whole code and put what i think is important, if you think you can help but require clarifications please do not hesitate to tell me)

```
void NetworkServer::acceptClientSocket()
{    
sockaddr * dummy = NULL;
while (ClientSocket = accept(ListenSocket, dummy, NULL)){
    if (ClientSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
           printf("accept failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
           closesocket(ListenSocket);
           WSACleanup();
           exit(1);
        }
        unsigned threadID;
        hThread = (HANDLE)_beginthreadex(NULL, 0, &handleClientRequest, (void*)ClientSocket, 0, &threadID);
    }
    closesocket(ListenSocket);
}
```

And the handleClientRequest function that looks like this:

```
unsigned __stdcall handleClientRequest(void* data)
{
SOCKET client_socket = (SOCKET)data;

DataReceiver dataReceiver(client_socket);

dataReceiver.receiveClientData();

return 1;
}
```

After hours of debugging i saw that the program reaches the return an then hangs. I know that _endthreadex is called immediately afterwards but the program still hangs. The data receiver is an object that does it's job perfectly according to the debugger.

Please help.

Comment: Visual Studio's debugger will show the **next** statement using a yellow arrow. If you don't have source code for the current statement it will look like the current statement has run to completion. Open the *Disassembly* window to actually see the current assembly instruction. In your case it may appear that `return 1` is the current statement if you don't have source code for `dataReceiver.receiveClientData()`. I would be surprised if the latter isn't a blocking call, so your current statement is likely in there.

Comment: @IInspectable i have done what you said and i found that it reaches the line  'call        __endthreadex (0F1A36E0h)' and tells after that Disassembly cannot be displayed in run mode. And it still doesn't reach the close socket line. The debugger actually reaches the return 1 statement, and then i go to the disassembler

Comment: @IInspectable and after that call to endthreadex i have the call add         esp,4  but it never reaches there as far the disassembler allows me to.

Comment: Looks like chicken-and-egg to me.  That while() loop only stops when accept() fails.  Only way to do that is to jerk the floor-mat with shutdown().

Comment: You seem to have the wrong mental model of threads. Each thread is a separate, independent unit of execution. Your call to `closesocket` will be issued when `_beginthreadex` returns. This usually happens a long time before the new thread calls `_endthreadex`. `_beginthreadex` will **not** wait for the thread to terminate - it launches it, then returns immediately while the new thread runs.

Comment: @IInspectable I understand your point and I have thought about it and after some search on the internet used this solution 

`hThread = (HANDLE)_beginthreadex(NULL, 0, &handleClientRequest, (void*)ClientSocket, 0, &threadID);

WaitForSingleObject(hThread, INFINITE)`

But this also didn't work, should there be another solution that i am missing?

Comment: Launching a thread only to wait on it to terminate completely defies the purpose of multithreading. Since we don't know what `DataReceiver` is, we cannot help you with your question. I would recommend reading [Windows Sockets 2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740673.aspx) if you wish to learn network programming on Windows.