# how to accept multiple clients with a simple winsock tcp server?

Tags: c++, sockets, winsock2

I can't figure out how to accept multiple connections for a simple tcp server using winsock.

I've tried a couple different ways and I can't figure out how to get another connection to work. The first call to accept() seems to be the only one that works. Can someone provide a simple example of how to do this or explain what's going on with listen() and accept() here?

```
#include <string>
#include <Winsock2.h>

WSADATA WsaData; 
unsigned char packet_in[64];
unsigned short port = 29992;
unsigned int max_packet_size =  sizeof(packet_in);
sockaddr_in xaddress;
SOCKET sock;
SOCKET sock1 = INVALID_SOCKET;
SOCKET sock2 = INVALID_SOCKET;

int main()
{   

    int r = WSAStartup( MAKEWORD(2,2),  &WsaData );
    xaddress.sin_family = AF_INET; 
    xaddress.sin_port =  htons(port);
    DWORD nonBlocking = 1;
    sockaddr_in from; 
    int fromLength = sizeof( from );  
    int count = 0;

    sock = socket( AF_INET,  SOCK_STREAM,  IPPROTO_TCP );   

    r = bind(sock, (const sockaddr*) &xaddress,  sizeof(sockaddr_in));
        if (r != 0) printf("%d\n", WSAGetLastError());

    r = listen(sock, SOMAXCONN);
    if (r == SOCKET_ERROR)
            printf("%d\n",WSAGetLastError());

    ioctlsocket(sock, FIONBIO, &nonBlocking);

    while(true)
    {

        if(count == 0)
        {
            sock1 = accept(sock, NULL, NULL);

        }
        else if (count == 1)
        {
            sock2 = accept(sock, NULL, NULL);

        }

        if(sock1 != INVALID_SOCKET)
            count = 1;
        if(sock2 != INVALID_SOCKET)
            count = 2;
        printf("%i\n",count);


    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Does it get inside your second `if statement -- if (count == 1)`? You should post the output and errors you get after a call to `WSAGetLastError`.

Comment: Try:

`struct sockaddr_storage ss; socklen_t slen = sizeof(ss); SOCKET fd = accept(listener, (struct sockaddr*)&ss, &slen);  ioctlsocket(sock, FIONBIO, &nonBlocking);`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TCP Winsock: accept multiple connections/clients](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15185380/tcp-winsock-accept-multiple-connections-clients)

Comment: Get rid of the non-blocking mode. You don't have anything else to do in the accept thread, or you shouldn't.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to network programming on Windows, but it basically looks like on Linux, so this is small example for Linux.

```
struct sockaddr_in server_addr
socklen_t len = sizeof(server_addr);
...
while(1)
{
   struct sockaddr_in client_addr;
   int client_fd;
   if((client_fd = accept(server_sock, (struct sockaddr*)& client_addr, &len)) < 0)
   {
      cerr<<"accept() error"<<endl;
      continue;
   }
   ...
}
```

There is full example written in Polish, but you should understand:
[full example (find //server.c)](http://cpp0x.pl/artykuly/?id=66)

Main differences between network programming on Windows and Linux are structures and classes, so it should give you some knowledge: [Beej's guide to network programming](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/)

Answer (score 0):

- **I think from this simple program, You will get better idea :)**

  ```
  // Multi-Client - Server chat application

      #include"header.h"

      void isr(int n)
      {
      printf("Client is Disconnected ..\n");
      kill(getpid(),9);
      return;
      }

      main()
      {
          int sockfd,nsfd,len,pid,size;
          char buffer[500],buffer1[500];
          struct sockaddr_in server;
      ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
          sockfd=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);
          if(sockfd==0)
          {
          printf("Socket file is not created socket is fail...\n");
          return;
          }
          ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
          server.sin_family=AF_INET;
          server.sin_port=htons(9898);
          len = sizeof(server);
        /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
          bind(sockfd,(struct sockaddr*)&server,len);
          perror("bind");
        /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
          listen(sockfd,5);
          perror("listen");
         /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
          bzero(buffer,sizeof(buffer));
          zero(buffer1,sizeof(buffer1));
          //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
         while(1)
         {
          nsfd=accept(sockfd,(struct sockaddr *)&server,&len);
              if(nsfd<0)
              {   
                  perror("accept");
                  return;
              }

             if(fork()==0)
              {
                  while(1)
                  {
                      size=recv(nsfd,buffer,sizeof(buffer),0);

                      if(size==0)
                      {
                      printf("Server is Disconnected...\n");
                      return;
                      }

                  printf("Data:%s\n",buffer);
                  bzero(buffer,sizeof(buffer));

                  }
             }
          else
          {
              printf("Enter the massage:\n");
              signal(17,isr);

                while(1)
                {
                    gets(buffer);
                    send(nsfd,buffer,strlen(buffer)+1,0);
                     bzero(buffer,sizeof(buffer));
               }
          }            
    }
  }
  ```